# show a modal when I click on the image, show another one when I click on the button

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've created 2 modals, I need to make one visible when I click on the image (a simple Lightbox basically) and show modal2 when I click on the cart button (top right of the image). I've duplicated the first modal (also its css and js functions) and edited the second modal.  I've tried a lot of things but I'm pretty sure it's something that I've missed. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
 
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
 
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}
 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
 
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
 
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
 
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height:50vh;
  max-width:1220px;
 
}
.modal-content img{width:300px;}
 
 
 
 .modal2 {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
 
/* Modal2 Content */
.modal2-content { 
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height:50vh;
  max-width:1220px;
 
}
.modal2-content img{width:300px;}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
 
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
 
 .mySlides2 {
  display: none;
}
 
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
 
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
 
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
 
/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
 
 .numbertext2 {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
 
 
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}
 
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
 
.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
 
img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
 
.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
 
 
 
 
 
.column {display: inline-block;
  position: relative;}
.row .column button {
 
     position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right:-15px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.BtnCart:hover{color:red;}
</style>
<body>
 
 
<!--immagini front-end -->
<div class="row">
 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://safarisnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/DSC_0180.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    <button class="BtnCart"  onclick="openModal2();currentSlide(1)"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
 
  </div>
 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      <button class="BtnCart" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
  </div>
 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
      <button class="BtnCart" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
  </div>
 
  <div class="column">
 
    <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/mountain.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 <button class="BtnCart" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
 
<!-- immagini nella light box-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="background-color:white;">
 
 
 
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content" >
 
 
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    </div>
 
 
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    </div>
 
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    </div>
 
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/mountain.jpg" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    </div>
 
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
 
 
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>
 
 
 
    <!--MODAL 2-->
 
   <!-- immagini nella light box-->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal2" style="background-color:white;">
 
 
 
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal2()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content" >
 
 
    <div class="mySlides2" >
      <div class="numbertext2" style="background-color:red;">1 / 4</div>
      <!-- TABELLA -->
        <table style="border:0px; width:auto; height:100vh; margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; border-spacing:0px ;padding:0px" >
    <tr>
    <td style=" width:60%; margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;background-color:white; border:0px;">
    <img src="https://safarisnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/DSC_0180.jpg" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;padding:0px; display:block; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
 
    </td>
 
    <td style=" width:50%;margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;background-color:white; border:0px;  vertical-align: middle;"><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <img style=" display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; vertical-align: middle; " 
  src="https://safarisnc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Senza-titolo-2-2.png" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;"> <br><p style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;"><a style="  text-align: center;" href="www.google.com"><b style="font-style:'TeXGyreAdventor';color:black;text-decoration:none;">Y45</b><br><span style="font-style:'TeXGyreAdventor';color:black;text-decoration:none;">Tecnico e funzionale con <br> apertura a Y</span></a><br><br><button style="background-color:white;color:black;border:0.5px solid black;">ACQUISTA ORA</button></p><br><br></td></tr></table>
 
    </div>
 
 
    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext2">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    </div>
 
    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext2">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    </div>
 
    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext2">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/mountain.jpg" style="width:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    </div>
 
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
 
 
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div> 
 
 
 
 
 
 
    <!--AIUTOOOOO-->
 
<!-- immagini preview slides -->
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/person.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/mountain.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/mountain.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://blocks.instituteofcode.com/images/mountain.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}
 
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}
 
//OPEN MODAL 2 function
function openModal2() {
  document.getElementById("myModal2").style.display = "block";
}
 
function closeModal2() {
  document.getElementById("myModal2").style.display = "none";
}
 
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
 
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
 
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
 
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
 
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.key === "Escape"){
 document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
    }
});
 
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.key == '37'){
plusSlides(-1);
    }
});
 
 
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.key == '39'){
 
}
});
 
 
 
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're finding?  You said what you want to do, but you didn't say what happens when you run this code.

Comment: I ran your code in jsfiddle, but it seems to have multiple problems.  I did see the image carousel when I clicked on an image, but it didn't size correctly.  Clicking on the shopping cart did not do anything.

Comment: So when I click on the image I should be able too image with lightbox, when I click on the cart button it is supposed to show me  modal2.